# Could picamera capture images without adjustment?

Tags: camera

I'm performing measurements using the picamera to test its sensor ov5647. But whenever I took images, it seemed there were adjustments. Gain, white balance and etc. Could I turn off all the adjustment function and just take raw image data? I know there is a bayer format, but I'm not sure if it is the data without adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bayer format captures contain the data prior to *almost* the entire image processing pipeline (demosaic, auto-gain, auto-white-balance, lens-shading, denoise, etc. etc.). The one exception is flips; if you've set `vflip` or `hflip` you need to account for the Bayer pattern being flipped accordingly, but that's it. Other than, it's the raw (10-bit) data straight from the sensor. See the [bayer capture recipe](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/recipes2.html#raw-bayer-data-captures) for information on unpacking the 10-bit format and a rudimentary de-mosaic algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear answer. But if you don't mind, I'd like to ask one more thing. Could I avoid auto-gain adjustment by fixing ISO speed? I'm considering using RGB565 format and wondering if I can still disable the auto adjustments.

Comment: No - I'm not exactly certain what fixing the ISO setting does, but I can say it doesn't fix the automatic gains. Fixing the gains can be done by setting `exposure_mode` to `'off'`. However, be aware that this will simply fix the gains (which can be queried with `analog_gain` and `digital_gain` where they are); at the moment the firmware provides no means of setting the gains to specific values.